Windows server 2019, file permissions not inherited after copying or moving a file
How can we ensure that copied and moved items inherit the permissions of the destination after moving the item from the parent folder on the same volume?
When an Antek user copies or moves a scan from the SCANS folder to the Office or Company folder, the Mikołaj, Filip, Natalia and Maciej users do not see the selected file.
We have set an entry in the registry according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/permissions-on-copying-moving-files
Value name: MoveSecurityAttributes
Data type: DWORD
Value data: 0

Unfortunately it didn't help.

It didn't help because that Registry setting is relevant to moving or copying files to another NTFS volume. You're copying them to another folder on the SAME NTFS volume. Additionally, that Registry setting is for maintaining the source permissions, which is not what you're trying to do. You're trying to inherit the destination permissions when you copy files to another folder on the same NTFS volume.

@joeqwerty it is exactly as you wrote

You need to change the setting you created to the opposite value: 0.
